# Can I airdrop an image from Chrome to my iPhone?

Tags: photos, google-chrome, airdrop, chrome-extensions

I don't want to share the web page or the link. I know we can do that today.
I want to airdrop an image after right clicking on it or opening the image in new tab, airdrop directly to my iphone photo gallery.

Comment: I can do it on Safari and I got your avatar on my iPhone. can you try it on chrome ? What's the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

there is no way as i know only you can do is to save that image and then airdrop it